# Find a closed form $g_n$ defined by $g_n = \prod_{k=1}^n (1+\frac{1}{k!})$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

One can derive a recurrence for $g_n$ as $g_n = g_{n-1}+g_{n-1}\frac{1}{n!}$, and letting $g_n = \sum_{j=0}^n a_j x^j$ gives a formula for the characteristic polynomial as $n! a_n x^n - \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}a_j x^j=0$. I feel like this is not a bad start but I can't think of what to do next, any ideas?

Comment: Any reason to expect that a closed form exists? OEIS [A238695](https://oeis.org/A238695) lists the *infinite* product as "*conjectured to be irrational, transcendental and normal, none have been shown*".

Comment: @VIVID The question here is about the (finite) partial products, though.